# Sympy substituting many variables with powers

Tags: python, sympy

Really, this is two questions in one.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
from sympy import *

x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3 = symbols("x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3")

term = x1**5 + (x2**2)*(x3**3) + x1**4 + x1**3 + x1**2 + x1

term = term.subs(x1**2, y1)
term = term.subs(x2**2, y2)
term = term.subs(x3**2, y3)
```

After the above, `term` takes the value `x1**5 + x1**3 + x1 + x3**3*y2 + y1**2 + y1`.

Question 1: I would like to turn all x_i^(2n+1) into the form x_i*(y_i^n) - but this leaves the odd powers of x_i alone. Is there any way to achieve this?

Question 2: Is there a way of typing something like `term = term.subs(xi**2, yi)`, rather than rewriting the substitution for each x_i?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems to work. Just be aware of the difference in the index base.

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x1 x2 x3")
y = symbols("y1 y2 y3")

term = x[0]**5 + (x[1]**2)*(x[2]**3) + x[0]**4 + x[0]**3 + x[0]**2 + x[0]
for i in range(3):
  term = term.subs(x[i]**2, y[i])
  for n in range(3):
    term = term.subs(x[i]**(2*n+1), x[i]*y[i]**n)
term
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding: `for n in range(3)`. When scaling upwards (say to range(5)), it seems to be wise to change it to `for n in range(reversed(5))`. Say we had an x_1^9: without reversing, the `subs(x[0]**3, x[0]*y[0]` changes this to (x_1^3)*(y_1^3), but then there will not be a substitution for the remaining x_1^3. Perhaps some while loop with a check on the powers of the x_i would work?

Answer (score 1):

You can just tell the `replace` method to find powers with odd exponents and replace them as you described in the OP.

[image]

The `sym` lambda is a function to give a new symbol to use for the odd case. In the first example [15] I use the integer attribute to create a new symbol that looks like the one appearing in the power but behaving distinctly (since symbols are known by their attributes). In the second example, I assume that only the first letter is going to be replaced with `y` (like you had said).

Since the replace does not care about the name of the variables, there is no need for an explicit loop to check all bases.

Comment: This is a nice way of doing things, but I feel like it could lead to problems. In the first example, after we change x^3*y^4 to x*x^2*y^4, we can then do `eq.subs(x**2,y)` to get x*y^5, as desired. But, unless I'm mistaken, the remaining x cannot now be manipulated directly since we never made an explicit name for it.

Another way to do it is to put `temp = symbols("temp")` and then `sym = lambda x: temp`, then at the very end we can just do `eq.subs(temp,x)`.

Comment: Never mind, we can just do `eq.subs(sym(x),x)`. Leaving the comments here in case they help others who get similarly confused.